# How to plot a histogram for cache hits and cache misses using python

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I have been trying to plot a histogram for cache hits and cache misses using python.
i have the following data:

```
 Histogram_scale   hit       miss 

   0:          0          0
   5:          0          0
  10:          0          0
  15:          0          0
  20:          0          0
  25:          0          0
  30:          0          0
  35:          0          0
  40:          0          0
  45:          0          0
  50:          0          0
  55:          0          0
  60:          0          0
  65:          0          0
  70:          0          0
  75:          0          0
  80:          0          0
  85:          0          0
  90:          0          0
  95:          0          0
 100:          0          0
 105:          0          0
 110:          0          0
 115:          0          0
 120:          0          0
 125:          0          0
 130:          0          0
 135:          0          0
 140:          0          0
 145:          0          0
 150:          0          0
 155:          0          0
 160:          0          0
 165:          0          0
 170:          0          0
 175:      49025          0
 180:        565          0
 185:        224          0
 190:         83          0
 195:         33          0
 200:         36          0
 205:          9          0
 210:          3          0
 215:          3          0
 220:          2          0
 225:          2          0
 230:          1          0
 235:          1          0
 240:          0          0
 245:          0          0
 250:          1          0
 255:          1          0
 260:          0          0
 265:          0          0
 270:          2          0
 275:          0          0
 280:          1          0
 285:          0          0
 290:          0          0
 295:          0          0
 300:          1          0
 305:          1          0
 310:          0          0
 315:          0          0
 320:          0          0
 325:          0          0
 330:          0          0
 335:          0          0
 340:          0          0
 345:          0          0
 350:          0          0
 355:          0          0
 360:          0          0
 365:          0          0
 370:          0          0
 375:          0          0
 380:          0          0
 385:          0          0
 390:          0          0
 395:          1          0
 400:          0          0
 405:          0          0
 410:          0          0
 415:          0          0
 420:          0          0
 425:          0          0
 430:          1          0
 435:          0          0
 440:          0          0
 445:          0          0
 450:          0          0
 455:          0          0
 460:          0          0
 465:          0          0
 470:          0         41
 475:          0        642
 480:          0        347
 485:          0        161
 490:          0        100
 495:          0        143
 500:          0      31469
 505:          0      10334
 510:          0        164
 515:          0        101
 520:          0         59
 525:          0         86
 530:          0         80
 535:          0         78
 540:          0         68
 545:          0         48
 550:          0         29
 555:          0         75
 560:          0         60
 565:          0         70
 570:          0         70
 575:          0         60
 580:          0         19
 585:          0         63
 590:          0         54
 595:          0         61
 600:          0         69
 605:          0         58
 610:          0         26
 615:          0         69
 620:          0         60
 625:          0         63
 630:          0         72
 635:          0         44
 640:          0         22
 645:          0         67
 650:          0         63
 655:          0         59
 660:          0         73
 665:          0         57
 670:          0         28
 675:          0         74
 680:          0         65
 685:          0         56
 690:          0         53
 695:          0         38
 700:          0         14
 705:          1         71
 710:          0         71
 715:          0         70
 720:          0         58
 725:          0         61
 730:          0         28
 735:          0         91
 740:          0         69
 745:          0         91
 750:          0         69
 755:          0         65
 760:          0         30
 765:          0         87
 770:          0        100
 775:          0         72
 780:          0         91
 785:          0         60
 790:          0         29
 795:          0         76
 800:          0         90
 805:          0         75
 810:          0         16
 815:          0         78
 820:          0         69
 825:          0         75
 830:          0         74
 835:          0         76
 840:          0         37
 845:          0        219
 850:          0        225
 855:          0        201
 860:          0        187
 865:          0        166
 870:          0         75
 875:          0        187
 880:          0        201
 885:          0        155
 890:          0         83
 895:          0         21
 900:          0         10
 905:          0         19
 910:          0         22
 915:          0         13
 920:          0         19
 925:          0          9
 930:          0          7
 935:          0         22
 940:          0         19
 945:          0         16
 950:          0         11
 955:          0         17
 960:          0          6
 965:          0         11
 970:          0         16
 975:          0         10
 980:          0          7
 985:          0         10
 990:          0          6
 995:          0         18
1000:          0         13
1005:          0         16
1010:          0         15
1015:          0         15
1020:          0          4
1025:          0         12
1030:          0         10
1035:          0         15
1040:          0         16
1045:          0         10
1050:          0          7
1055:          0         14
1060:          0         11
1065:          0          6
1070:          0         10
1075:          0          6
1080:          0          5
1085:          0         12
1090:          0          5
1095:          0          6
1100:          0          5
1105:          0          3
1110:          0          4
1115:          0          4
1120:          0          5
1125:          0          3
1130:          0         12
1135:          0          7
1140:          0          5
1145:          0         15
1150:          0          7
1155:          0         10
1160:          0          9
1165:          0          6
1170:          0          6
1175:          0         16
1180:          0         16
1185:          0         12
1190:          0         12
1195:          0          7
1200:          0          8
1205:          0          8
1210:          0          3
1215:          0          8
1220:          0          7
1225:          0          2
1230:          0          2
1235:          0          1
1240:          0          3
1245:          0          2
1250:          0          3
1255:          0          4
1260:          0          4
1265:          0          2
1270:          0          4
1275:          0          8
1280:          0          0
1285:          0          5
1290:          0          1
1295:          0          1
1300:          0          3
1305:          0          5
1310:          0          3
1315:          0          2
1320:          0          0
1325:          0          2
1330:          0          3
1335:          0          0
1340:          0          1
1345:          0          1
1350:          0          3
1355:          0          2
1360:          0          1
1365:          0          2
1370:          0          2
1375:          0          1
1380:          0          3
1385:          0          2
1390:          0          1
1395:          0          1
1400:          0          2
1405:          0          0
1410:          0          0
1415:          0          0
1420:          0          0
1425:          0          1
1430:          0          0
1435:          0          1
1440:          0          0
1445:          0          0
1450:          0          2
1455:          0          0
1460:          0          1
1465:          0          2
1470:          0          0
1475:          0          1
1480:          0          0
1485:          0          1
1490:          0          0
1495:          3         24
```

Now i'm trying to understand how to plot this values using matplotlib and following some threads here i wrote a simple python code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab

# Creating dataset 
arch = "miss"
list_miss = []
for item in open(arch,'r'):
    item = item.strip()
    if item != '':
        try:
            list_miss.append(int(item))
        except ValueError:
            pass


arch = "hit"
list_hit = []
for item in open(arch,'r'):
    item = item.strip()
    if item != '':
        try:
            list_hit.append(int(item))
        except ValueError:
            pass

# Creating histogram 
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize =(10, 5)) 
plt.hist(list_miss,bins='auto',alpha=0.9,color='red', label='miss')
plt.hist(list_hit,bins='auto',alpha=0.9,color='blue', label='hit')
#plt.xlim(0,200)
     
#plot
plt.xlabel('Measured access time')
plt.ylabel('Number of Access')
plt.legend()
    
plt.show()
```

But i did not get the desired result.
Can anyone help me to understand how to do it and set the right values ?

Thank you.

Comment: The part describing how you measure hits and misses is probably irrelevant for this question and should be deleted - it just leads people looking at this question to the assumption this is a rather complicated matter. Instead you should provide a shorter input sample (maybe 10 data points) with the exact format used by you (is it a list of list? a pandas dataframe? a sample file?) that people can use in their IDE. Finally, how does the output differ from your expectation? I suggest editing the question to attract answers.

Comment: @Mr.T do you mean the exact format of the values in the c file ?

Comment: It seems you want to read in a file, so it would be good to store a sample file externally that users can download to test their approach. I still don't know, though, how the output differs from your desired result. What are the "right values", and what do you see instead?

Comment: @Mr.T I should see two gaussian over the histogram but i don't

Comment: @Mr.T the values that are read from files are those that I have inserted in the question

Comment: Maybe it is me but I do not see, where you read from the file. Is this a text file, a pandas file, an excel file, a csv file, two files? We don't know. You should provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In the meantime - have you tested that your lists list_miss and list_hit contain the expected numbers? Have you checked that with an expected list pair list_hit and list_miss the expected histogram is produced? This will (hopefully) narrow down the problem to one of the two program steps.

Comment: @Mr.T the files "hit" and "miss" are two text files which contains the values i wrote in the question.

Comment: @Mr.T Yes, the list_miss and list_hit contain the expected numbers. I checked it